# How do I move a line in a text file up or down by one line?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have some text files, and I'd like to be able to *move* an arbitrary line in any of the files up or down one line (lines at the beginning or end of the file would stay where they are).  I have some working code but it seems kludgy and I'm not convinced I have all the edge cases covered, so I'm wondering if there's some tool or paradigm that does this better (e.g. easier to understand the code (for other readers or me in 6 months), easier to debug, and easier to maintain; "more efficient" isn't very important).

```
move_up() {
  # fetch line with head -<line number> | tail -1
  # insert that one line higher
  # delete the old line
  sed -i -e "$((line_number-1))i$(head -$line_number $file | tail -1)" -e "${line_number}d" "$file"
}

move_down() {
  file_length=$(wc -l < "$file")
  if [[ "$line_number" -ge $((file_length - 1)) ]]; then
    # sed can't insert past the end of the file, so append the line
    # then delete the old line
    echo $(head -$line_number "$file" | tail -1) >> "$file"
    sed -i "${line_number}d" "$file"
  else
    # get the line, and insert it after the next line, and delete the original
    sed -i -e "$((line_number+2))i$(head -$line_number $file | tail -1)" -e "${line_number}d" "$file"
  fi
}
```

I can do error checking of inputs inside or outside these functions, but bonus points if bad input (like non-integers, non-existent files, or line numbers greater than the length of the file) are handled sanely.

I want it to run in a Bash script on modern Debian/Ubuntu systems.  I don't always have root access but can expect "standard" tools to be installed (think a shared web server), and *may* be able to request installation of other tools if I can justify the request (though fewer external dependencies is always better).

Example:

```
$ cat b
1
2
3
4
$ file=b line_number=3 move_up
$ cat b
1
3
2
4
$ file=b line_number=3 move_down
$ cat b
1
3
4
2
$
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Similar to *Archemar*'s suggestion, you could script this with `ed`:

```
printf %s\\n ${linenr}m${addr} w q | ed -s infile
```

i.e.

```
linenr                      #  is the line number
m                           #  command that moves the line
addr=$(( linenr + 1 ))      #  if you move the line down
addr=$(( linenr - 2 ))      #  if you move the line up
w                           #  write changes to file
q                           #  quit editor
```

e.g. to move line no. `21` one line up:

```
printf %s\\n 21m19 w q | ed -s infile
```

to move line no. `21` one line down:

```
printf %s\\n 21m22 w q | ed -s infile
```

But since you only need to move a certain line up or down by one line, you could also say that you practically want to swap two consecutive lines. Meet `sed`:

```
sed -i -n 'addr{h;n;G};p' infile
```

i.e.

```
addr=${linenr}           # if you move the line down
addr=$(( linenr - 1 ))   # if you move the line up
h                        # replace content of the hold  buffer with a copy of the pattern space
n                        # read a new line replacing the current line in the pattern space  
G                        # append the content of the hold buffer to the pattern space
p                        # print the entire pattern space
```

e.g. to move line no. `21` one line up:

```
sed -i -n '20{h;n;G};p' infile
```

to move line no. `21` one line down:

```
sed -i -n '21{h;n;G};p' infile
```

---

I used `gnu sed` syntax above. If portability is a concern:

```
sed -n 'addr{
h
n
G
}
p' infile
```

---

Other than that, the usual checks: file exists and is writable; `file_length > 2`; `line_no. > 1`; `line_no. < file_length`;

Answer (score 3):

there is a vi command called move `m`

you can use vi in text mode : ex

```
  $line_number=7
  $line_up=$(($line_number + 1 ))
  (echo ${line_number}m${line_up} ; echo wq ) | ex foo
```

where

- `foo` is your file

Answer (score 0):

With vims (use vim in sed mode): https://github.com/MilesCranmer/vim-stream

You can:

```
cat file.txt | vims "$NUMBERm.-1"
```

To move the line down by one.