# Increment value and swap next two lines

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file with a sequence of lines repeating multiple times. For example:

```
param id: 0
value: 2
description: "hello"

param id: 1
value: 3
description: "world"
```

I want to move *description* above *value* and change *param id* to one value higher, like *param id* 1 instead of 0. I want to do this using scripting.
Can somebody help me with the commands that can achieve this?

Comment: can you edit your post with a sample of expected file ?

Comment: You should also show what you've attempted so far with your `sed` commands.

Comment: to move the lines up and down, please see answers to [THIS QUESTION](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/188078/how-do-i-move-a-line-in-a-text-file-up-or-down-by-one-line). Incrementing the value is a different matter and `sed` is not the correct tool for it. May be `awk` ??

Answer (score 1):

As has already been suggested by @MelBursian in the comments, I also would favor `awk` over `sed`.

```
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS=FS=": " }
    {
        if ($1 == "param id") {
            $2 += 1;
        }
        if ($1 == "value") {
            val=$0; getline;
            print; print val;
            next;
        }
        print;
    }
' file
```

Comment: This can be shorter in pattern/action style: `awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=": "} $1=="param id"{$2++} $1=="value"{getline t;print t} 1' file`

Answer (score 0):

This will switch all lines that start with "value: " with the respective next line:

```
sed '/^value: /{N;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2\n\1/}'
```

Expanation:

- `/^value: / { ... }` will execute the commands in braces (here the fake `...`) only for the lines that match the regular expression "^value: "
- `N` will append the next line to the pattern space. So we can operate on two lines joined by a newline from here on.
- `s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2\n\1/` will switch the text before the newline with the text after the newline.

  - `s/something/else/` is the replace command that will replace "something" with "else"
  - `^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$` will match any text from the beginning of the pattern space to a new line char and save it as expression one, and then all further chars to the end of the pattern space will be saved as expression two
  - `\2\n\1` will put expression two followed by a newline and then followed by expression one as the replacement

Answer (score 0):

To increment a value with `sed` is extremly not recommended. it's not the correct tool for such a job. But if it has to be `sed`, this works only with GNU `sed`.

```
sed -rn '/^param/{s/(.*)([0-9]+)/echo \1$((\2+1))/e;p;n;h;n;p;x;p;n;p}' file
```

---

- `-r` activates extended regular expressions.
- `-n` disables `sed`'s auto-printing.
- `/^param/` search for a line starting with the pattern `param`.

  - `s/(.*)([0-9]+)/echo \1$((\2+1))/e` now do a search/replace in that line. Search for number `([0-9]+)` and replace it with `echo \1$((\2+1))`, which then is executed. `e` in `s///e` is the modificator that executed the matched pattern in a shell.
  - `p;` then prints the altered line.
  - `n;` loads the next line in the pattern space (the `value` line).
  - `h;` copies that line into the hold space.
  - `n;p;` loads the next line (the `description` line) and prints it.
  - `x;` exchanges the pattern and the hold space.
  - `p;` prints that line.
  - `n;p` loads the next line (the empty line) and prints it.

---

The output with your example input:

```
param id: 1
description: "hello"
value: 2

param id: 2
description: "world"
value: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

The line moving is most easily done with POSIX `ex`; the numeric increment is most easily done with `awk`.  Fortunately, `ex` allows you to filter specific lines through external tools:

```
printf %s\\n 'g/description/m-2' 'g/param id/.!awk "++\$NF"' x | ex file
```

Translated into English, the first command is "Move all lines that contain the word 'description' one line up."

(There's a 2 there because, more literally translated, it's "Move these lines to the point just after the lines two lines up.")

The second is, "Filter each line that contains 'param id' through `awk`."

The `awk` command is, "Increment the final field of the line (and print the line, unless the result happens to be zero. :)"

`x` is "Save and exit."